# Error Upgrading from ASP.NET 5 Beta 4 to Beta 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have followed the steps [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/06/30/asp-net-5-beta5-now-available.aspx) to upgrade from ASP.NET 5 Beta 4 to Beta 5 but am getting an error at runtime when calling `application.UseBrowserLink();`:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.IApplicationBuilder' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Http, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

These are the steps I followed:

1. Had VS 2015 RC already installed.
2. From PowerShell run:
       `$env:DNX_FEED="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2"`
3. From PowerShell run: `dnvm upgrade`
4. Added a Global.json file (I did not already have one). When I added it, it referred to Beta 5 already:

   ```
   {
       "projects": [ "Source", "Tests" ],
       "sdk": {
           "version": "1.0.0-beta5-12103"
       }
   }
   ```
5. Updated all packages in project.json to Beta 5. You can see a full version of my project.lock.json file [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/719).

   ```
   {
     "dependencies": {
       "Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6": "1.0.2",
       "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Xml": "6.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
       "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5",
       "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.6",
       "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-23019"
     }
     "frameworks": {
         "dnx451": {
           "frameworkAssemblies": {
             "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0",
             "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
           }
         },
         "dnxcore50": {
           "dependencies": {
             "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-beta-23019"
           }
         }
       }
   }
   ```
6. The instructions then go on to say you should run the following commands but I believe VS 2015 RC does this for you `dnu restore` then `dnu build`.

**UPDATE**

It seems to be a problem with browser link, commenting the line out allows the site to work. It may be broken? Need to hunt around the aspnet GitHub issues.

Comment: Related https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/719

Comment: The latest dnx runtime from the stable NuGet feed is `1.0.0-beta5`, yet you are referencing to nightly build `1.0.0-beta5-12103` in your `global.json`. Perhaps changing the sdk version `1.0.0-beta5` helps.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to help you migrate from beta4 to beta5, these are the following steps it took me, based on the research/findings.

## Environment

- PowerShell run: `$env:DNX_FEED="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2"`
- PowerShell run: `dnvm install 1.0.0-beta5`
- PowerShell run: `dnvm use 1.0.0-beta5 -p` (*not sure if its needed however i had to*)

## Project

- Open global.json and update sdk to 1.0.0-beta5 should look like this:

  ```
  {
      "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
      "sdk": {
          "version": "1.0.0-beta5"
      }
  }
  ```
- Open project.json:

  - Updated dependencies versions from beta4 to beta5
  - Change **Configuration** dependency from:

    ```
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4"
    ```

    to

    ```
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5"
    ```
  - Remove `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader`
  - Rename `_GlobalImport.cshtml` to `_ViewImports.cshtml`

### Startup.cs changes

- Change Configuration breaking changes

  - Change namespace from `using Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel;` to `using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;`
  - Change `Configuration.GetSubKey` to `Configuration.GetConfigurationSection`
  - Change CTOR to:

    ```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {           
        // Setup configuration sources.
        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = configBuilder.Build();
    }
    ```
  - Remove `app.UseBrowserLink();`

## Project DNU CMDs

- Open PowerShell within **app root**
- Run `dnu restore`
- Run `dnu build`
- Closing and reopening VS at this point helps sometimes.

Myself found it quite difficult to upgrade an existing project, couldn't find all steps required all together.
Hope it helps!

Comment: If you could update your experience for beta 6. That would be appreciated.

Comment: Excellent info and research, thanks.
MS have seriously dropped the ball with VS2015... and sadly with everything in their post Win-7 era :(

Answer (score 5):

To complete, if you want to update from beta 4 to beta 6, see the Stephen Lautier's answer and to this after :

**To update from beta 5 to beta 6 :**

I did :

- Open global.json and update sdk to "1.0.0-beta6" and save this file
- Visual Studio 2015 proposes to download beta6, click on Yes

In project.json :

- change dnx451 (or dnx452) to dnx46 (To use Framework 4.6)
- replace all "-beta5" with "-beta6" in this file
- remove Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets

In Startup.cs, if you use Session :

- replace app.UseInMemorySession(...) with app.UseSession()
- In ConfigureServices, add this :

  ```
   services.AddCaching();
   services.AddSession();
   services.ConfigureSession(o => {    o.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); });
  ```
- Right click on your Project > Properties > Debug > Add a new Environment Variable :

> **Name :** DNX_IIS_RUNTIME_FRAMEWORK
>
> **Value :** dnx46

See that for more information : http://jameschambers.com/2015/07/launching-an-asp-net-5-application-from-visual-studio-2015/

- In Package Manager Console, write this "dnu restore" and this "dnu build"
- Restart Visual Studio

My project work in beta6 after that, maybe there are other things to do.

Comment: Why did you remove Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets?

Answer (score 2):

After speaking with @davidfowl from the ASP.NET vNext team, he told me that Browser Link doesn't work in beta5 and should be removed.

Comment: We're looking into it

Comment: They do have a reference to Browser Link when you go to File->New Project in VS2015 RTM

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft.AspNet.Http and Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Core package names swapped](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/7)

Comment: I've tried adding both but still does not work. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

This is the thing:

You updated the DNX from beta4 to beta5, and you want to run an MVC6 template inside Visual Studio RC (whose templates were built around beta4).

In the first place, `"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json"` doesn't exist in beta5 anymore. (you should definitely see this: https://github.com/aspnet/announcements/issues?q=milestone%3A1.0.0-beta5 - breaking changes from beta4 to beta5).

In order to see that your DNX was updated properly, build a new empty web project and simply add MVC/WebAPI (simple cases to check that it works).

I haven't tried to run the MVC template yet, but I will try and come back to you.

Comment: "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json" was renamed to "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json". It does exist.

Comment: Yes, you are right. :) Have you succeeded in running the template?

Comment: Btw, You should try the MVC6 template without authentication, as EF has suffered some changes: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/35

Comment: Not using EF. The template runs fine after commenting out the browser link line.

Comment: Ok, I got in contact with @davidfowl from the ASP.NET vNext team and he told me that BrowserLink is broken in beta5 and I should remove it

Comment: If you want to play around with the new beta5, install Yeoman which gives you basic templates for webapps, including the mvc template (including EF)

Comment: Where can I find the GitHub page for those project templates?

Comment: The best thing you can do is install Node (if you don't have it already) and install Yeoman for asp.net 5, then you can create functional beta 5 templates (MVC Web App, Web App without authentication etc).

I haven't found them on GitHub so far.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering how to update to ASP.NET 5 Beta 7, I found it useful to download the latest ASP.NET and Web Tools updates for Visual Studio 2015 and then create a new ASP.NET 5 project in Visual Studio.

This will create a Beta 7 project with the project structure, code and referenced dependencies for you. You can then use this as a guide to upgrade any existing older Beta projects.

For example here what my project.json looks like using all the Beta 7 dependencies:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-WebApplication1-a433a0ef-3bed-4bc9-8086-8d18070fa2c1",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug" : "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta7"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

At the time of writing, this is where you can download [the beta 7 updates for Visual Studio](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623894). Ensure you get the file WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi.

Find more information about this Beta 7 release see the blog post [Announcing Availability of ASP.NET 5 Beta7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta7.aspx)