# Upgrading ASP.NET 5 from beta-4 to beta-5

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, dnvm

Upgraded ASP.NET5 from beta-4 to beta-5 following the instructions on Microsoft's site: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/06/30/asp-net-5-beta5-now-available.aspx

Got ton's of compile errors (1900+) like I was missing core .NET stuff (System.Object not defined, etc).  I followed the solution posted at this other similar question: [Error Upgrading from ASP.NET 5 Beta 4 to Beta 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218651/error-upgrading-from-asp-net-5-beta-4-to-beta-5)  But this did not resolve the issue.  I now get errors that the following runtime could not be found:  dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta5

If I run the command "dnvm list" I get the following output:

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture
------ -------           ------- ------------
       1.0.0-beta4       clr     x64
       1.0.0-beta4       clr     x86
       1.0.0-beta4       coreclr x64
       1.0.0-beta4       coreclr x86
  *    1.0.0-beta6-12254 clr     x86
       1.0.0-beta6-12254 coreclr x86
```

So dnvm upgrade skipped over beta5 and went straight to beta6, but it appears some things are still looking for beta5.  Is there a way to force dvnm to install beta5?

I've attempted to run the command:

```
 dnvm install 1.0.0-beta5
```

Which results in the error:

```
'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6-12254' is already installed.
```

Notice it says beta6 for the error!  Perhaps it's being used as an alias for beta5 or it's just not possible to install earlier versions?

Answer (score 0):

`dnvm` installs from the release feed by default. We've branched for beta6 and beta5 is not longer on that feed.

To solve the issue, set the DNX_FEED variable:

```
set DNX_FEED=https://nuget.org/api/v2
dnvm install 1.0.0-beta5
```

PS: [I've opened a bug](https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm/issues/354) to track this. It would be nice to have a regular argument to specify the feed.

Comment: I did have DNX_FEED set.  I needed to remove the alias using dnvm alias 1.0.0-beta5 -r before "dnvm install" would work.  I don't know why this alias was ever added!

Comment: Maybe it was because you ran alias with the parameters in the wrong order? :) I did that before

Comment: Never ran alias other than to remove the alias.. I think it might be added as part of the beta6 install?